# Upload PDF using requests in Python

Tags: python, api, pdf, python-requests

I am trying to upload a pdf file to an API using requests in python.
In Postman e.g. I can use the body and select "binary" to upload the file. How can I do this in Python? (payload="")
The Content-type needs to be application/pdf

The PDF needs to be downloaded from an URL.

Thanks in advance

I tried to use PyPDF to read the file from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

First, define the headers that your upload request will have. Then get pdf from remote url and save its content to the memory. After that, just use a post request with specified headers to upload the document.

```py
headers = {'content-type': 'application/pdf'}
pdf = requests.get('http://mypdfurl').content
requests.post('http://myserver/upload', headers = headers, data = pdf)
```